# How to log Exceptions in Nlog2?

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

I am a bit confused what way is the right way to log exceptions

```
 Log.Fatal(exception format, args);
```

or

```
  logger.FatalException("Got exception.", ex);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like mostly a matter of preference. I tend to use the `log.FatalException("blah", ex)` model for two reasons.

1. That's clearly what it's there for.
2. You have a bit of control over the format of how the exception is displayed in the nlog configuration. See: https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/How-to-log-exceptions

Comment: Hmm ya. Well I am using the ninject exception logger interface and it does not have FatalException so wondering if I should go through the trouble and add it or if I should just you the overload method.